# How to execute n-gram code from github

Tags: github-pages, n-gram

My question is how to run code [`MITRECND/snugglefish`](https://github.com/MITRECND/snugglefish) in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have clone [`MITRECND/snugglefish`](https://github.com/MITRECND/snugglefish) in a local folder on your computer, you would [use `NMAKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx) in order to interpret the Makefile.
Since [NMAKE is he native Windows alternative to the Linux make utility, with a very similar syntax](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/makefiles-windows/), the `Makefile` might not be fully compatible, but should be adapted, once you see errors.

Once that passes, use **[`CMake`](https://cmake.org/)** in order to generate a Visual Studio solution. See "[CMake and Visual Studio](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/)".